# .NET REST PUT CURL API

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, rest, curl

ok I have this curl statement that works

```
curl -i -u user:pass -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "type=menu&title=HelloWorld" http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pages/
```

but I cant get it to work in .net.

I have tried restsharp

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pages/");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "pass");

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");


            // add parameters for all properties on an object
            request.AddParameter("type", "menu");
            request.AddParameter("title", "HelloWorld");


            // execute the request
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
            richTextBox1.Text = content.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and straight .net

```
 Private Sub ButtonPost_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonPost.Click

    address = New Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pages")

    ' Create the web request  
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)

    ' Set type to POST  
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "Accept: application/json"

    ' Add authentication to request  
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("user", "pass")

    Dim str As String = "type=men&title=HelloWorld"
    ' Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
    byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str)

    ' Set the content length in the request headers  
    request.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    ' Write data  
    Try
        postStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not postStream Is Nothing Then postStream.Close()
    End Try

    Try
        ' Get response  
        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        ' Get the response stream into a reader  
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        ' Console application output  
        RichTextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to have a definition of the behavior when you "can't get it to work"

Comment: I have tried lots and lots of different ways and in the RestSharp it usually says Forbidden (sometimes bad request) and in the  straight vb.net is usually says internal server error 500

Comment: you can email me at pmtolk  gmail and I will give you the user and pass if you want to test something!!!

Comment: Awesome! An all-caps question title that needs no correction.